GraphQL `in` operator is not working when using Azure Static Web App
I am using Azure Static Web App with Azure SQL database. When filtering the data, I want to use the in instead of the eq operator. So far the eq operator is working as expected:
async function filterProducts() {
  const query = `
    query Products {
      products(filter: { category: { eq: "dairy" } }) {
        items {
          date
          category
          price
        }
      }
    }`;
  
  const filteredProducts = await fetch('/data-api/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: query })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((dataJson) => {
      const dataItems = dataJson.data.products.items;
      const dates = dataItems.map((product) => product.date);
      const prices = dataItems.map((product) => product.price);
      return { dates, prices };
    })
    .catch((err) => console.warn('Unable to fetch from the endpoint.', err));

  return filteredProducts;
}

However, using the in operator will get a 400 status (Bad Request) error. This is the input query:
  const query = `
    query Products {
      products(filter: { category: { in: ["dairy", "fruit"] } }) {
        items {
          date
          category
          price
        }
      }
    }`;

And I got the error when calling the localhost:4280/data-api/graphql endpoint:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Is it possible to use the in operator from an Azure Static Web App? How to filter multiple values using GraphQL in Azure Static Web App?

are using GraphQL & Gatsby

@Sampath I am not using the gatsby package. I only use the query string and send it to the GraphQL API which is generated via Azure Static Web App CLI tool.

which tool you have used

@Sampath I have created a Svelte application.

The https://stackoverflow.com/a/78345944/10721627 answer is incomplete because it only retrieves 100 data by default. To gather all the data, we need to use the hasNextPage as a return statement and reassign the afterCursor to the endCursor variable in each iteration.
async function filterProducts() {
  let allProducts = [];
  let pageSize = 1000;
  let hasNextPage = true;
  let afterCursor = null;

  // Fetches all data from the endpoint using pagination.
  while (hasNextPage) {
    const query = `
      query Products {
        products(first: ${pageSize}, after: ${afterCursor}) {
          items {
            date
            category
            price
          }
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
      }
      `;

    await fetch('/data-api/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: query })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataJson) => {
        allProducts = allProducts.concat(dataJson.data.products.items);

        hasNextPage = dataJson.data.products.hasNextPage;
        afterCursor = `"${dataJson.data.products.endCursor}"`;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.warn('Unable to fetch the data from the `selectAllMaterialStock` endpoint.', err);
        hasNextPage = false;
      });
  }

  // Filters the data using the fields.
  const categories = ['dairy', 'fruits'];
  const filteredProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => categories.includes(item.category));

  return filteredProducts;
}

We are appending the fetched data into the allProducts array. Once we have the complete data, we can filter it with the built-in Array.prototype.filter() method since the in operator cannot be used, see the previous answer.

Note: If there is huge data, this solution will not be the most performant alternative. A possible alternative could be to use the mssql package to directly query the database.


The recent Graph REST API supports $filter with in condition. The sample url for it will be like ~/users?$filter=mail in ('mail1@domain.com', 'mail2@domain.com'). I hope you can try ("dairy", "fruit") rather than ["dairy", "fruit"].

References
Graph API - Use the filter query parameter

Unfortunately, replacing the filter with ("dairy", "fruit") is not working. It returns with the same error. I checked the GraphQL schema using Postman and it does not contain the in operator.

@PéterSzilvási
I tried this sample https://lucasconstantino.github.io/graphiql-online/ and it worked fine.
query countries {
countries(filter: { name: { in: ["Andorra", "United Arab Emirates"] } })
{
name
}
}
Can you check what you are getting in err ? I would say the GraphQL query seems to be fine.

I think that there is a limitation on the Azure Static Web App's GraphQL server.

After starting the Static Web Application (SWA), I introspected the GraphQL schema with Postman. Since I am using the Svelte frontend framework, the development server is listening on the 5000 port. So I provided the http://localhost:5000/graphql in the URL, went to the Schema tab, and loaded the schema with the "Using GraphQL introspection.". Back to the Query tab, I can search the available filtering options:

Regarding the Static Web App's GraphQL API, I cannot see the in filtering options. It is possible to check equality, containing or starting with conditions using a single string input.
With this limitation, I implemented a workaround by using a category list with a for loop, and the eq filtering option:
async function filterProducts() {
  let result = [];
  const categories = ['dairy', 'fruit'];
  for (const category of categories) {
    const query = `
      query Products {
        products(filter: { category: { eq: "${category}" } }) {
          items {
            date
            category
            price
          }
        }
      }`;

    const filteredProducts = await fetch('/data-api/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: query })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataJson) => {
        const dataItems = dataJson.data.products.items;
        const dates = dataItems.map((product) => product.date);
        const prices = dataItems.map((product) => product.price);
        return { dates, prices };
      })
      .catch((err) => console.warn('Unable to fetch from the endpoint.', err));

    result = result.concat(filteredProducts);
  }

  return result;
}

It loops through the desired categories, fetches them from the API endpoint, and then appends each category to a result array.

Note: It would be nice to use the in operator but since SWA has its limitation, I guess "we have to cook with what we have".

EDIT: Be cautious because the GraphQL (and as well as the REST) API retrieves data in batches. The default batch size is 100, so a pagination technique is necessary to fetch the entire data.
